# Why array with same types can't be unioned?

Tags: php

Its my first post in stackoverflow. I've started programming since 3 weeks ago. now I'm on operator. I'm a bit curious about union in array operators. I have this code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<?php
$x = array("a" => "red", "b" => "green");  
$y = array("c" => "blue", "d" => "yellow");  
$c = array(5, 6, 7, 8);
$d = array(9, 10, 11, 12);

print_r($x + $y + $d + $c); // union of $x and $y
?>  

</body>
</html>
```

i have tried all combination that possible, but for $c and $d, if i 'union' them, it always show only one of them. e.g i union $d + $c the output is:

```
Array ( [0] => 9 [1] => 10 [2] => 11 [3] => 12
```

Not a single array from $c shown there. Why doess it happen sensei??

Comment: what is your expected result? Maybe it's array_combine or array_push you are looking for?

Comment: `print_r(array_merge($x, $y, $c, $d));` may be what you're after

Comment: i expect  Array ( [0] => 9 [1] => 10 [2] => 11 [3] => 12 continued with [4]=> 5 [5]=> 6 and so on

Comment: to @Scoots i've tried it, its work. i forget to change + to , before

Comment: Use it : print_r(array_merge($x, $y, $d, $c));

Comment: $d is most definitley shown - there must be something else going on with your code: http://ideone.com/lLsQv5

Comment: @Scoots Here is the problem I think. He uses `+` instead of `,` https://3v4l.org/fHtGD

Comment: Ah yes, I missed his edited comment.

Answer (score 2):

It's because `$c` and `$d` have matching keys. From [docs on array union](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.array.php): "For keys that exist in both arrays, the elements from the left-hand array will be used, and the matching elements from the right-hand array will be ignored."

Answer (score 1):

`print_r($x + $y + $d + $c);` will overwrite the keys.

Instead use `array_merge()`.

Answer (score 1):

[Array_merge](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) is what you need.

```
<?php

$x = array("a" => "red", "b" => "green");  
$y = array("c" => "blue", "d" => "yellow");  
$c = array(5, 6, 7, 8);
$d = array(9, 10, 11, 12);

print_r(array_merge($x, $y, $d, $c)); // union of $x and $y
```

https://3v4l.org/T9vOT